# Pushing various objects in Javascript but save not properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm pushing various objects in an array.

```
$scope.itemsPending = [];

while(bonos.length > 0){

  if($scope.itemsPending.length > 0){
     console.log($scope.itemsPending);
  }

  bono = bonos.shift();
  if(bono.is_highlighted == false){
      aux.push(bono);
      maximo++;
  }else{
      if(maximo + 2 < 4){
           aux.push(bono);
           maximo += 2;
      }else{
           $scope.itemsPending.push(bono);
      }
  }
```

}

But when I show it in the dev console I have one or two "objects" and if I open this items, I have three.

[image]

What is happening?

EDIT

My bono value is like that

[image]

Comment: what is the initial value of bonos?

Comment: It's a object defined in a factory like in OOP with some attributes

Comment: Can you put the values in the question? It cannot be debugged without the values to know what should be the expected output and what is coming

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's console (for better or for worse) "logs" a reference to the object and when you inspect its contents by clicking on the arrow, it **shows the current value at that object**. This means that modifying an array within a loop and logging it on each iteration might have unexpected results.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AKxfxPnZ8bWO8LczZf4u?p=preview) is a simplified example demonstrating the issue. You should see the array being logged 3 times as `[Object]`, `[Object, Object]`, `[Object, Object, Object]`, but "expanding" each of these logs will access the current contents of the array and show you 3 elements in all cases.

To reliably log changes to an object, log a primitive value instead of an object or an array. For example, the length of the array, or a serialized version of the array.

---

Also, consider that in the alternative (in order to show the state of the object at the time it was logged), the browser would need to clone and retain every object that is logged. This would cause it to run out of memory very quickly.